# Access denied during drupal module install with composer

Tags: drupal, composer-php

While on windows,this command: `composer require drupal/field_group -w` results in an error:

```
[ErrorException]
rename(F:\Documents\work\projects\x2/vendor/composer/tmp-bb22b878ca9a5a45c963cc69e990dcf4.zip~,
F:\Documents\work\projects\x2/vendor/composer/tmp-bb22b878ca9a5a45c963cc69e990dcf4.zip): 
Access is denied. (code: 5)
```

The command window was 'Run as Administrator'.
The vendor folder, composer.json and composer.lock are not hidden.

Any thoughts?
thanks,
-dave.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is there any good reason to use an elevated prompt for this?

Comment: I am getting the same issue as above but it is in PHP Laravel. Could somebody help me out ? I am using WIndows 10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using adminitrator to execute the cmd?
[image]

You shouldnt use Administrator role to run composer commands.

But, you can try to run the next command, and execute the `composer require` again

```
chmod -R 777 F:\Documents\work\projects\x2/vendor/composer
```